# JBoss application failed to connect to OpenShift MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, jboss, datanucleus, openshift

I have an application running on JBossAS7 with MongoDB as database. The application is able to connect to the local MongoDB and perform data operations as expected. When I attempt to connect to the remote MongoDB hosted on OpenShift, the database connection can not be made.

After creating an OpenShift application and adding MongoDB cartridge, I ssh-ed to the OpenShift application server and typed in the command `env | grep OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB` to retrieve MongoDB host information as displayed below:

```
OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME=...
OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD=...
OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST=...
OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_GEAR_DNS=...
OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT=...
OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL=...
OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_GEAR_UUID=...
```

Since I am using DataNucleus JDO, following is how I set the properties of Persistence Manager Factory (PMF) in the JBoss application in hope to connect to OpenShift MongoDB with the above information:

```
properties.setProperty("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL","mongodb://[OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST]:[OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT]/[Database Name]");
properties.setProperty("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName",[OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME]);
properties.setProperty("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword",[OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD]);
```

Would really appreciate the help here. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple inspection of [documentation](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/datastores/mongodb.html) shows that

```
mongodb://[OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST]:[OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT]/[Database Name]
```

is invalid syntax. There are no double slashes in accepted syntax (unless your hostname really begins with double slash, which I doubt)